# Orbitdb and python

Tags: python, orbitdb

I have created a dApp with Flask that uses an sqlite3 local database. I am trying to remove the local database and create a decentralized one. I guess [orbitdb](https://orbitdb.org) is one of the possibilities. Although a page about the [python3 implementation](https://github.com/orbitdb/py-orbit-db-http-client) exists I could not find any similar project or any guide on how to implement the database.

Any help on how to create the database would be appreciated.